# Output formatted version of variable if it has a value, blank otherwise

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm looking to add an if statement to display a title if something is in a variable but not 100% sure how to go about it.

My current coding shows:

```
<?php echo $quote->getmessage(); ?>
```

But I would like it to show a title and the content of the message if there is content in the variable. If there is nothing within the variable I don't want to show anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO it's better to be as verbose as necessary so that the code is easily readable and can be extended without totally rewriting it:

```
<?php 
$message = $quote->getmessage();
if (!empty($message)) {
    echo "Title!";
    echo htmlspecialchars($message);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use php's [isset](http://php.net/isset) function to check if a variable is set, and [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) to see if it's empty.

For instance

```
<?php $a = $quote->getmessage();if (!empty($a)) echo $a; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo ($quote->getmessage() == "") ? "" : "Title <br />".$quote->getmessage(); ?>
```

Comment: that calls the functions **twice** why would you want to do that?

Comment: it is only a little how-to, not a perfect sollution. And it looks like OP want's to use inline-tags, and I think, in this case the shortest solution is the best one

Answer (score 0):

Use a ternary operator:

```
<?php 
   $quote_var = $quote->getmessage(); 
   echo ($quote_var != null)?$quote_var:'NOTHING!'; 
   //displays 'NOTHING' if the variable is null
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$mssg = $quote->getmessage();
echo (!empty($mssg))?$mssg:'';
?>
```

Comment: almost ;)
for the poster; check what your function returns if no message has been set, an empty string ('') or null? than you can determine if our friend Neal here has the right solution, or if I did :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want your line to be concise, then I would advise this syntax:

```
<?php  $msg = $quote->getmessage()  AND  print "<h6>title</h6>$msg";  ?>
```

The `AND` has a lower precedence than the assignment (but extra whitespace or braces make that more readable). And the second part only gets executed if the `$msg` variable receives any content. And `print` can be used in this exporession context instead of `echo`.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php 
     if(isset($quote->getmessage())
     {
         echo "My Title";
     }
?>
```